# Excel Formula/SQL to get calculated value in Access

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I had tables in MS Access.

Due to the size of the tables in Access, it is practically impossible to 'export' it into Excel.

Thus, am wondering if there's a way to "LINK" from Excel to Access.

In a sense, given the condition in Excel, it's able to 'calculate' tables/data that's in Access and spit out the result.

Comment: What are you trying to calculate? Why not just do it in Access?

Comment: The reason why am not doing in Access is that manager wants to create 'dashboard' type where there'll be multiple charts and 'data labels', with options to select from list (probably using combobox or data validation depending on circumstances).

Formulas could be INDEX, INDIRECT, OFFSET, MATCH, SUMIF etc...that's why there'll be multiple criteria.

Comment: Data tab > Connections > Access?

Comment: That will 'import' it to the excel table, and I don't want it that way, as the record in Access is over a million rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the ADO objects. They are a way to link Excel to Access database in the VBA environment.
You can turn them on from "Tools">"Reference" in the VBA editor, named "Microsoft Office/Excel 16.0 Object Library. See
[How to turn on ADO for VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/using-ado-with-microsoft-visual-basic) here.

Once you turn it on, you can use a particular set of objects such as ADODB.Recordset or ADODB.Connection to access your Access database, retrieve and calculate data from it, and eventually getting the data outputted just like any other VBA macros. Microsoft's site offers detailed explanation on how to explore. Good luck!